# Aggregating Rows in Data Frame while Combining Column Values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like this:

| Company | Response |
| --- | --- |
| Walmart | Chris - Issue |
| Walmart | Chris - Issue |
| Walmart | John - Other |
| Walmart | Jim - Issue |
| Walmart |  |
| Walmart |  |

And I would like to end up with something like this, where the values in the response column are combined and separated with a ";", while duplicates are removed (each response only appears once) and null values are excluded (for those that don't have value in response column).

| Company | Combined Response |
| --- | --- |
| Walmart | Chris - Issue; John - Other; Jim - Issue |

There will be a lot of different companies on the data frame I will be working with as well, not just Walmart, so hopefully there is a solution that I can apply to the entire sheet and have one entry for each company. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Blank values are NaN or empty string?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
out = df['Response'].dropna() \
                    .groupby(df['Company']) \
                    .apply(lambda x: '; '.join(x.drop_duplicates())) \
                    .rename('Combined Response') \
                    .reset_index()
```

Result:

```
>>> out
   Company                         Combined Response
0  Walmart  Chris - Issue; John - Other; Jim - Issue
```

Comment: Very fast, and very concise code! The only thing this does not accomplish is removing the duplicates, so that, for example, "Chris - Issue" only appears once in the output.

Comment: I don't understand. The output is what you expect? Do you have any whitespaces at the beginning or the end of responses?

Comment: Yes, this output is exactly what I was going for.  The blank values are NAN as many of the rows don't have anything in the response field.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```python
result = df.groupby("Company")["Response"].apply(lambda x: ";".join(list(set(list(x)))))
res = res.reset_index().rename(columns={"Response":"Combined Response"})


>>> res
   Company                       Combined Response
0  Walmart  John - Other;Chris - Issue;Jim - Issue
```

Comment: Thank you very much everyone! I just started learning Python a few months ago, and this was my first post here, so I appreciate your time and patience.

Answer (score 0):

If the same response is possible to appear in 2 companies, we cannot drop duplicates before using `.groupby()`.  To cater for this, we can use:

```
df.groupby('Company')['Response'].apply(lambda x: '; '.join(x.dropna().drop_duplicates())).reset_index(name='Combined Response')
```

To demonstrate, I added another company with similar responses:

**Input**

```
   Company       Response
0   Amazon  Chris - Issue
1   Amazon   John - Other
2   Amazon           None
3   Amazon    Jim - Issue
4  Walmart  Chris - Issue
5  Walmart  Chris - Issue
6  Walmart   John - Other
7  Walmart    Jim - Issue
8  Walmart           None
9  Walmart           None
```

Output:

```
   Company                         Combined Response
0   Amazon  Chris - Issue; John - Other; Jim - Issue
1  Walmart  Chris - Issue; John - Other; Jim - Issue
```